# Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode in angular material mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material mat-select component.

```
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort >

              <ng-container matColumnDef="sensitive">
                <mat-header-cell class="table-header header-p" *matHeaderCellDef> <b>sensitive</b> </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="table-content context-position "  *matCellDef="let element"  >
                  <mat-select placeholder="sensitive"  multiple [(ngModel)]="element.sensitive" >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let type of sensitiveList" [value]="type">{{type}}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <mat-header-row class="table-header-row" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
              <mat-row  [ngClass]="((i%2) == 1) ? 'table-content-row-single' : 'table-content-row-double'"  *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

typescript
         sensitiveList : string[] = [ 'none', 'sensitive'];
         for(var i=0;i

why running the code gives me an error

```
Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode
```

Comment: Can I see how does your `sensitiveList ` look like? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @wentjun just add it, it is just a array

Comment: this is not a way to respond to comments with questions in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a multiple select which is serving an array of data and your elements attribute 'sensitive' isn't an array! Change your attribute 'sensitive' to a string  array or remove the 'multiple' from your mat-select to get a single value and your problem should be solved

Comment: I don't get it, can you give an example?

Comment: element.sensitive is a NOT an array but databinding in this case requires an array here because the select has the 'multiple' directive

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem. I passed as array and still get the error. The problem for me was that I set a default value for the formContol.
for example:

```
myFormControl: new FormControl(1);
```

The problem is that the default value should be an array.
So, to set the default value for a `mat-select` with `multiple` attribute, you should do the following:

```
myFormControl: new FormControl([1]);
```

After doing this the problem is solved.